# C# .NET - Application startup error after it's installed

Tags: c#, installation, publish

I run my program in visual studio and it works great, but when i publish it and installed it dont start. I checked the problem on the event viewer and it's the information that comes with the error:

> Faulting application name: Screen recorder.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time 
>        stamp: 0x59f8f3ad
>        Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.23915, time stamp: 
>        0x59b94abb
>        Exception code: 0xe0434352
>        Fault offset: 0x0000c54f
>        Faulting process id: 0x22f8
>        Faulting application start time: 0x01d35294634fde75
>        Faulting application path: C:\Users\jmarin\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\LAHCHL75.EB9\PJ1V31LT.BZW\scre..tion_b46dd58387405837_0001.0000_c9a5ed0df210aa7f\Screen recorder.exe
>        Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
>        Report Id: a1aed905-be87-11e7-849a-989096bc2875
>
> Application: Screen recorder.exe
>        Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>        Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>        Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>        at ScreenRecord.Form1..ctor()
>        at Screen_recorder.Program.Main()

Comment: Well, it's a `FileNotFoundException` so presumably it's not finding some file you are trying to open, but since your question is lacking any sort of code....

Comment: As it says: `FileNotFound`. Does your program needs some files or dll's? Compare the contents of  your local Release folder with the pulish destination.

Comment: Yes, it has a differents dlls form Aforge, where i can put them for publish them ?

Comment: How do you publish the application? ClickOnce? InstallShield?

Comment: I published it using the publish wizard from visual studio

Comment: It's been many years since I used the publish function of VS. It's based on ClickOnce deployment, and one thing I remember is that sometimes we had to tweak the deployment manifest so that all needed resources were included. I'm not saying this is the cause of your error, but I think it's worth making sure you're deploying all the required DLLs. In some cases, we had to use a tool to create the manifest file manually. Forgive me for my poor memory :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException**
Please look into your code, you are using file which is not available while publishing. you can copy the file into the root directory and try it again